# ios - making app delete and update core data in the background (objective c)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, timer

I want my app in objective-c to delete the core data and then reload it in the background, so the user can still use the current core data. I want this to happen every 30 seconds then have it update on screen, is this possible?

Comment: should this be done in background when user just changes apps or even when user quits apps?

Comment: While the user is still using the app. I have it connected to a mysql database, so I want it to pull new information every 30 seconds in the background then update it on the screen. So the user can still use the app while this happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by having a multithread that makes the call to the api and updates core data while running the app

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //Background Thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Run UI Updates
    });
});
```

Inside the dispatch_async you can have it call himself with a timer, that way, when finished updating the database, it will wait for more 30 seconds until the next call

```
[self performSelector:@selector(YourFunctionName) 
       withObject:(can be Self or Object from other Classes) 
       afterDelay:(Time Of Delay)];
```

Now, be careful as this can create some memory management issues

Comment: Can I put the code for the new thread anywhere, or is there a certain way to implement it?

Comment: app delegate would be a good idea, that way you are sure that it will always be run, or on you main ViewController. which one you think is better

Comment: Also, when I dispatch to the main thread will it interfere with what the user is currently doing (cause lag)?

Comment: you should create a method on appDelegate and call that method on applicationDidBecomeActive, that way you can call it again

Comment: How do I make the changes appear on the main screen? cant get this to work

Comment: try using NSNotificationCenter, that way you can update on the main screen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44460326/ios-error-when-using-threads-and-core-data-objective-c, get the following error